# JSF2 load yaml propertie files as resource bundle

Tags: jsf-2, yaml

We are updating our web app to use only yaml properties.
But in some xhtml view files the application is reading properties file to resolve url.
I want to know if is it possible to load yaml file as resource bundle in JSF2:

```
<h:form id="frmMenuHeader">
        <f:loadBundle basename="application" var="config" />
        <p:menubar id="barMenuHeader" styleClass="menuHead">
            <p:menuitem id="selMenuHeader" value="Início" url="index.xhtml"
                styleclass="homeMenuHead" />
            <p:submenu id="btnConteudoMenuHeader" label="Conteúdo">
                <p:menuitem id="btnConteudoNovoVideoMenuHeader" value="Novo Víde
```

When i access the page it shows me:

> /common/header.xhtml @40,56 
>   Can't find bundle for base name application, locale pt_BR

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related (other than you using it)

Comment: Though that was important to tag

Comment: Try in a page without the `p:menubar` does it fail too? Then it is not PrimeFaces related. Or try in a fully vanilla jsf project... Does it fail there.... Root cause analysis... debugging... Cheers

Comment: So you enter this post just to complain about the tag ?                     
What about the answer?

Comment: I'm mainly helping out on PrimeFaces things and secondary on JSF stuff. In that regard I read **every** post that is made with these tags, **every**  edit, **every** comment etc... First thing I always do is to check if the tagging is right and how it is related to one of the tags. If not, that is the first thing I talk about or directly correct (tagging is for where the problem is, not what you use, you could tag it 'intel' or 'amd' as well since that is most likely used too and 99% sure this is not YAML related e.g.). <more>

Comment: Then I **HELP** to narrow down the problem by pointing out steps to do that. Most important step is to create a [mcve]. Then most likely there is no PrimeFaces tag in that page anymore and the file is not YAML etc... But if you do not want to do all those things, you obviously do not want to be 'helped' but you want an out of the box complete solution. Well, that change is low, simply because with what you all posted the real cause cannot be seen and effectively this question is a duplicate of all the others about _"Can't find bundle for base name <bla>, locale <any locale>"_ Good luck

Comment: So you´re the tag police man on stack overflow?I just put primefaces because i dont know if the problem is with primefaces,i just put beucase i though is important to indicate that i´m using it.When i have doubt on tags i ask you. Can´t believe this...

Comment: @Romulo: my post(s) tags are also modified by users possessing suficciant reputation. This is helpful to target the correct audience. Kukeltje is definitly one of them and explained why/how. You should return to the facts of your question and modify as adviced by Kukeltje. (Minimal, Complete, ...)

Comment: Also my question is "I want to know if is it possible to load yaml file as resource bundle in JSF2:" So is not a duplicate from other "Can't find bundle for base name <bla>, locale <any locale>" he should read the question carefully.